# Sql function for finding a guid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I'm trying to do is search through a specific column in my database and pull out any rows that match a pattern (i.e. any rows where the nvarchar contains a guid).

I've got this function.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[HasGuid] (
    @Data varchar(50)
) RETURNS bit WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
BEGIN 
    return case when @Data like REPLACE('%00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]') then 
               1 
           else 
               0 
           end 
END
```

It works on most of my data

values it works on:

```
12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234.ext
sometext:12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234:c:\path\12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234\12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234.ext
sometext:12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234.ext
```

values it doesn't work on:

```
c:\path\12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234\12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234.ext
```

Where .ext is one of any number of different extensions and the 1234 guid is just representative and not actually the same guid multiple times in any one string.

And I'm using the function like so (should be obvious, but just to be complete)

```
SELECT * from SomeTable s
WHERE dbo.HasGuid(s.SomeColumn) = 0
```

At this point I would expect to see only the rows where that column is not a guid but I'm getting the discrepancy above.  I'm not seeing what's wrong in my function, but if someone could point out what I'm missing it'd be super helpful.

Comment: It works for me on `c:\path\12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234\12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234.ext`

Comment: It must be an azure sql thing then..

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It looks like it's just a shortcoming of azure sql.  It works as expected outside of azure.</strike>

I figured out the actual issue.  The @Data declaration was too limiting.  The following is the updated function.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[HasGuid] (@Data nvarchar(400)) RETURNS bit WITH SCHEMABINDING AS BEGIN return case when @Data like REPLACE('%00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]') then 1 else 0 end END
```

It's still a difference between azure sql and mssql, but at least it's figured out now.